# Rails gem for custom authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am new to rails and am wanting to make a training scheduling app. I need a user management system and am sure one exists as a gem but I cannot seem to find one with all of these needed features.

- Multiple access levels (User, Trainer, Manager, Admin)
- No user signup (Trainer, Manager, Admin will create accounts and the information will be emailed to users)
- User groups (User, Trainer, Manager) belong to groups and can only manage users in those groups. Admin can manage anyone in any group.
- Users can change details on their account and change their passwords.
- Admins can determine how users will login (custom field, username, email)
- Can use a mysql database

Is there any current gems out there with all this functionality or will a custom one need to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining two concepts here, **user authentication** and **role-based access control**. Consider using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication as it's quite configurable (you can disable the sign_up route and only allow sign_in, for example), and something like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for rbac.

Also, do you really need to allow admins to determine how users will login? Consider just settling on one method to start with, and adding this functionality later if it's a real priority.

Comment: I would prefer to allow login by a custom field such as an 6 digit id number. I figured roles and login would be together. However it does seem to make sense that they would be different plugins. Do these plugins support MySQL?

Comment: You can authenticate based on any field, although you may have to write a custom controller to handle that (no worries though, that's supported by the devise gem, and it'll even scaffold the controller for you). As long as a database is supported by ActiveRecord (yes, mysql is one of them) then it'll work with any rails gem worth its weight. Several gems also support nosql stores as well.

Comment: Does cancan allow the user groups with Trainers and Managers being able to only manage people in those groups while admins can manage anyone?

Comment: To do this with cancan, you'd add methods to `User` like `is_trainer?` and `is_manager?` (which can check if the user is in that group, or however you want to model that in the database). Then you can limit what a user can do by something like `authorize! :update, @user` in a `before_filter` in the controller that updates the other user.